# How to unit test the catch exception statement?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

How do I test the catch statement below? My coverlay is failing and I am not sure how to cover this line.

```
public Method execute(@NonNull final String test) throws ServiceException {
    try {
        object = javaClient.fetchInfo(test);
    } catch (ClientException | InternalServerError e) {
        throw serviceExceptionAdapter.apply(e);
    }
    return object;
}
```

This is currently what I have in my test file:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
    this.serviceExceptionAdapter = mock(ExceptionAdapter.class);
    this.mockJavaClient = mock(JavaClient.class);
    proxy = new Proxy(mockJavaClient, serviceExceptionAdapter);
}

@Test
void test_InternalServerError() {
    when(mockJavaClient.fetchInfo(any())).thenThrow(InternalServerError.class);
    when(serviceExceptionAdapter.apply(any())).thenThrow(ServiceException.class);

    assertThrows(ServiceException.class, () -> proxy.execute(test));
    verify(serviceExceptionAdapter, times(1)).apply(any());
}
```

Comment: In the catch statement you have 2 posible error cases ClientException and InternalServerError. You have to write 2 tests where will be thrown both of those types .thenThrow(ClientException .class); and .thenThrow(InternalServerError.class);

Comment: I have another test for the ClientException (same thing as the InternalServerError) as well but the line is still not being covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to guess a little bit, as you didn't provide a full working example. From what I see in your catch block

```
} catch (ClientException | InternalServerError e) {
    throw serviceExceptionAdapter.apply(e);
}
```

you expect the return value of your `.apply(e)` function to be an exception and throw that exception. In your test however, your mocked `serviceExceptionAdapter` doesn't return an Exception, but throws one instead:

```
when(serviceExceptionAdapter.apply(any()))
   .thenThrow(ServiceException.class);
```

If my interpretations are correct, your code should work if you change the mentioned line in the test to the following:

```java
when(serviceExceptionAdapter.apply(any()))
   .thenReturn(new ServiceException(...));
```